# Where to include javascript instances in drupal

Tags: javascript

I've added my.js using js injector module and updated .info file.
Where do I have to create those instances?
Sorry, I'm new with technology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Add any `js` file to your Drupal site , a good way is to create a custom module and add your `js` file there.Following points may help you.

- Create one custom module of yours. Useful Link. https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7
- In your module , create one folder name `js`.
- Add your js file here.You can copy paste your js file also here.
- Now in your`module file` the following code to tell drupal about your js file.

  ```
  function YOURMODULENAME_init(){

   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULENAME') . '/js/yourjs.js');

  }
  ```
- At the end enable your custom module.You are ready to go.