# How to add jquery to drupal basic page

Tags: nodes, forms, ajax, javascript

I want to add few jquery in my basic page of drupal website to call some api with parameter. Can any one explain me how can i accomplish this. $.ajax or $.post we can do right but its not happening in basic page.
I wanted to **triggerd that jquery when i click html submit button**... *in this case i am not using hook_form actully.**

This is only for one page...basically its a drupal basic page.

Comment: Try this [link] http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192008/where-to-include-javascript-instances-in-drupal/192027#192027

Comment: You have to provide more details; do you want this JS to be added on all pages, or only on some of them, do you want to do this through your theme or custom module, and so on.

Comment: I just noticed the "***don't want to create module for this.***" notice in the revision log of this question ... I think that's a crucial "notice" that you should include in your actual question, eg via a "Note: ..." at the end ...